# How to compute floor(log2(5**x)) without floating point arithmetic or long integer computation

Tags: math, floating-point

The problem is how do we compute the integer value of floor(log2(5^x)) without floating point arithmetic or long integer computation? I'm looking for a simple, efficient and mathematically elegant way.

Observations:
The formula is just the number of bits in 5**x (plus 1)

Attempts:
I tried to simplify it to:
floor(x*log2(5))

In my use case, x is not extremely large, probably just 1-100. While an elegant formula that works for small values would suffice me, I would be interested in a formula/algorithm that works for any value of x

I'm making a reference software implementation of universal numbers (type III). I want to make everything easily convertible to microcode by purely using bitwise and basic operations. This is one of the formulas i need to simplify.

Comment: The number of bits in 5**x is ceiling(x*log2(5)), not floor. You need 3 bits to store 5**1.

Comment: I think it's floor(x*log2(5)) + 1. Let me verify.
Edit: yup, seems like im right. f(2) = f(3) works when we use floor then add 1, but doesn't work for ceil.

Comment: I think you are right. 4 requires 3 bits to store it.

Comment: For the limited size case, could you use a system with long integer arithmetic to compute a table? For each integer n in [1,N], compute the smallest integer power of 5, x, that such that 2**n is no greater than 5**x. Store a mapping between x and n.

Comment: yeah, with x <= 100, it shouldnt be hard. the ditgis after 5 digits, don't matter after multiplication, so we can just perform ~5 digit integer multiplication. interested in seeing other approaches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for a simple, efficient and mathematically elegant way...  `floor(x*log2(5))`

Since `x` has integer values 1 to 100, various tests can to made to find the "best" that uses an integer multiply and a divide by power_of_2.
 `f(x) = x*a integer_divide power_of_2`

For
`f(x) = floor(x*log2(5)) = floor(x*some_float_c)` the value of `some_float_c` is bounded by 100 minimum and maximums below.

```
x   f(x)    mn  mx
        f(x)/x  (f(x) + 1)/x
1   2   2.00000 3.00000
2   4   2.00000 2.50000
3   6   2.00000 2.33333
... 
59  136 2.30508 2.32203
... 
87  202 2.32184 2.33333
... 
98  227 2.31633 2.32653
99  229 2.31313 2.32323
100 232 2.32000 2.33000
```

The maximum min is `2.32184` and the minimum max is `2.32203`, :

```
2.32184... <= some_float_c < 2.32203...
```

Since we cannot use `float`, find `some_integer/some_power_of_2`

```
2.32184... <= some_integer/some_power_of_2 < 2.32203...
ceil(some_power_of_2 * 2.32184...) <= some_integer < floor(some_power_of_2 * 2.32203...)

        min     max
        2.32184 2.32203
2       5       4
4       10      9
8       19      18
...
1024    2378    2377
2048    4756    4755
4096    9511    9511  < first one where min <= max
8192    19021   19022
```

So `9511/4096` is the "simplest" and is a "best" candidate.

```
f(x) = (x*9511) integer_divide_by_power_of_2 4096

// In C
unsigned y = (x*9511u) >> 12;
```

Answer (score 4):

As you correctly note, `log2(5**x) == x * log2(5)`. `log2(5)` is a constant, which can be approximated to `2.3219281`.

However, floats aren't allowed per the question. Not an issue!

```
log2_5 = 23219281;
scale = 10000000; // note log2_5/scale is the actual value
result = x * log2_5;
output = (result - (result % scale)) / scale;
```

By reducing `result` by `result % scale`, dividing it by `scale` will be an integer division, not a float.

Comment: As an alternative, you can just do `output = result intdiv scale` where `intdiv` is integer division with truncation, as this will handle your `floor` requirement too.

Comment: yeah it would be necessary too since i cant use float operations

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very rough approximation, but it can help if you want to obtain it mentally

```
5^3 = 125
2^7 = 128
```

So for raising to the power of n:

```
5^n ~~ 2^(7n/3)
```

So 5^12 is near 2^28 might require up to 29 bits.

It's a bit overestimated because 2^7 > 5^3, so 28 bits are enough, a good usage is to simply round the fraction upper.

If I evaluate in Smalltalk:

```
(1 to: 50) reject: [:i | (5 raisedTo: i) highBit = (i*7/3) ceiling].
```

I get:

```
#(31 34 37 40 43 46 49)
```

You see that the very simple formulation works up to 5^30 which is not that bad.